# Como puedo generar un XML con CreateElement principal y el nombre del nod

Tags: c#, mvc, xml

Buen dia soy nuevo en este tema de XML lo estoy realizando desde C# pero quiero llegar a este objetivo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera crear mi XML con esta estructura XS:ELEMENT
por lo que entiendo XS es el nombre root principal y element es el nombre del nodo

no se si estoy mal... pero aun no logro crearlo de antemano gracias,

**UPDATE**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi se me muestra pero quisiera anadir USUARIO: ID, USUARIO:NOMBRE

**UPDATE 2**

```
 public ActionResult CreateXML()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode docnode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
        doc.AppendChild(docnode);

        XmlElement dte = doc.CreateElement("Usuario");
        (dte).SetAttribute("xmlns:ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
        (dte).SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        (dte).SetAttribute("Version", "0.1");
        doc.AppendChild(dte);

        XmlNode hearNode = doc.CreateElement("Usuario:Id");
        //agregarle el atributo
        XmlAttribute atr = doc.CreateAttribute("ClaseDocumento");
        atr.Value = "NORMAL";
        hearNode.Attributes.SetNamedItem(atr);
        dte.AppendChild(hearNode);


        var basePath = Path.Combine(@"D:\Users\Edgar\Desktop\Views", @"XMLFiles\");
        //if (!Directory.Exists(basePath))
        //{
            Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath);
        //}
        var newFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), ".xml");
        doc.Save(basePath + newFileName);


        return View();
    }
```

Te sere sincero esto es lo unico que tengo,  desde mi vista le doy clikc a un button y me genera el XML, el resultado que optengo es este.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si te das cuenta yo en mi intento quiero poner Usuario:Id en el siguiente nodo pero me tira solo Id se que debo de andar lejos, ya que soy nuevo en este tema, gracias por la comprension

**UPDATE 3**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Lo que necesitas generar es un schema de XML? Por que dices "xs:element"... asi que deberias ver o de investigar como crear en C# un Schema XML. Que seria la "estructura" o el "template" de un XML (para validarlo). Pero con esto puedes investigar y colocar codigo especifico de generar el schema y poder hacer una pregunta mas especifica.

Comment: @JoseA.Fernandez ya pude crear mi XML desde c# todo bien... pero me lo muestra asi <Libros>  <Autor name=''etc'></Autor>     </Libros pero yo quisiera que me lo mostrara con ese sobre nombre   <Libros: "Alias">  <Libros:Autor name=''etc'></Autor>     </Libros  de esta manera

Comment: @JoseA.Fernandez no muy capto como es que esos ejemplos utilizan xs que es el elemento principal para todos los nodos de abajo es como usar un div: "aca poner un nombre distinto como para identificarlo"

Comment: con tus comentarios puedes "mejorar tu pregunta", porque dices que ya generaste el XML. Asi que coloca el codigo de como generaste, como es tu clase/objetvo, como genero el XML y como necesitas que te genere. Asi te podremos ayudar mejor

Comment: entiendo, dame un segundo agradezo bastante

Comment: Buenas, esto es un xsd te paso un ejemplo de Microsoft de como generarlo
[enlace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschema?view=net-7.0) Si tienes dudas, actualiza la pregunta con el problema y el código.

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar? El "por qué" necesitas crear como "Usuario:Id" a cada elemento?  Porque el XSD es para validar un XML, y tu necesitas "crear un XML". Si nos comentas tu necesidad de podemos orientar. Ya que no es necesario yasi como lo planteas el XML estara "mal armado", un XML valido es como indicas en la imagen de como lo generas actualmente.

Comment: @JoseA.Fernandez puedes chequear por favor subi otro UPDATE 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El XML que indicas esta bien formado, porque agregar un namespaces como indicas (con el prefijo con el mismo nombre del objeto) no lo he visto, pero por eso preguntamos cual es la necesidad o requerimiento especifico
En el objeto que envias serializado, esta bien formado:

```
<usuario>
  <id>123</id>
</usuario>
```

y que quieres es agregar solamente a algunas propiedades un namespace (porque el ejemplo que envias es un XML llamado XSD que es un "esquema de definicion")
Lo que necesitas es algo asi:

```
<usuario>
  <usuario:id>123</usuario:id>
</usuario>
```

Para eso tienes que ver configurar tu objeto, para que indiques en toda la clase o en la propiedad que quieres que tenga dicho namespaces
Si colocas en la clase completa la configuracion te quedaria algo asi

```
 <usuario:usuario>
     <usuario:id>123</usuario:id>
 </usuario:usuario>
```

Veamos un ejemplo, te dejo un repositorio online con unas pruebas que actualice para que pueda servir de ayuda o guia

- https://github.com/fernandezja/serialization-experiments-dotnet
- Basicamente el proyecto es [SerializeAndDeserializeXml](https://github.com/fernandezja/serialization-experiments-dotnet/tree/master/SerializeAndDeserializeXml) donde podras ver

La clase [Jedi](https://github.com/fernandezja/serialization-experiments-dotnet/blob/master/SerializeAndDeserializeXml/SerializeAndDeserializeXml/Jedi.cs) que tiene los atributos que te comentaba indicando namespaces. Mira con el atributo XmlRoot (en la clase) o (XmlElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.namespace?view=net-7.0) en cada propiedad indicas el nombre que quieres que se serialice y tambien el namespaces correspondiente (es nombre y no el prefijo/alias del namespaces, en la serializacion indicas dicho "prefijo")

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "jedi", Namespace = "https://www.starwars.com")]
public class Jedi
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName ="id", Namespace = "https://www.starwars.com")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Luego [para serializar un ejemplo](https://github.com/fernandezja/serialization-experiments-dotnet/blob/0720398756bfe66bf205e504ba72858f0a662aed/SerializeAndDeserializeXml/SerializeAndDeserializeXml/JediManager.cs#L29) donde se indica en el metodo [Serialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.serialize?view=net-7.0) los namespaces para serializar con el prefijo correspondiente

```
public string SerializeWithNamespaces(Jedi jedi)
{
    var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    namespaces.Add("sw", "https://www.starwars.com");
    namespaces.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
  

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        _serializer.Serialize(stream: ms,
                              o: jedi, 
                              namespaces: namespaces);

        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Bueno en tu caso o ejemplo deberias
1 - Indicar cual es el Namespaces en tu clase o propiedades
2 - Al momento de serializar indicar el "prefijo"

Por ejemplo en tu clase Usuario en la propiedad Id

```
[XmlElement(ElementName ="id", Namespace = "https://demo.usuario.com")]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Y en la serializacion indicas asi

```
   var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
   namespaces.Add("usuario", "https://demo.usuario.com");
   namespaces.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

Para asi la serializacion del objeto quedaria algo asi

```
<usuario>
  <usuario:id>123</usuario:id>
</usuario>
```

Pruebalo, a indica si tienes algun inconveniente.

Enlaces que te pueden servir de ayuda o guia

- [Repositorio de Ejemplo https://github.com/fernandezja/serialization-experiments-dotnet](https://github.com/fernandezja/serialization-experiments-dotnet)
- [Procedimiento para calificar elementos XML y nombres de atributo de XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-qualify-xml-element-and-xml-attribute-names)

Comment: puedes chequear por favor mi POST, subi otro UPDATE 2

Comment: Ahi tienes un codigo en el UPDATE 2 para crear un XML "paso a paso", pero seria bueno saber de donde obtienes los datos para crear el XML. Para no estar haciendolo manualmente, sino que el mismo objeto o array de objetos usuarios lo serialices a XML (como el ejemplo que coloco donde el objeto/instancia de la clase Jedi lo serializo)

Comment: Fijate que tengo una clase Usuarios.cs con Id, Nombre, Apellido etc. Luego Hago una consulta a la  base de datos por SqlConecction (StringBuilder) lo devuelvo en un <List>, que ese List tendria que llegar a la funcion que puse en UPDATE 2... una vez que mi lista venga con datos ejemplo Usuario.Nombre y venga lleno como haria para serializar esa lista? y colocarlos en vez de datos manuales ya con las clases?

Comment: @edgar si tienes la clase Usuario (coloca la definicion) y lo ideal es que lo serialices como lo muestro en el ejemplo de esta respuesta. Dale unamirada y prueba. PEro no lo hagas manualmente elemento por elemento. Ya que esto te ayuda el serializador a XML

Comment: Coloque un UPDATE 3, de esa manera obtengo mi informacion ahora como lo pondria en CreateElement o en lugar de hacerlo manual, ya poner mi Lista

Comment: Amigo ya revise tu ejemplo de SERIALIZE ahora como puedo poner esas clases en el   XmlNode hearNode = doc.CreateElement("Usuario:Id"); donde dice usuario:id como podria meter las clases?